# cx_Freeze unable to generate standalone

Tags: python, macos, module, cx-freeze

I'm trying to generate a standalone build with cx_Freeze.
I'm running python3.1 on MacOS 10.5.8 with py31-cx_Freeze package from mac ports.

During the build, i've noticed the following:

```
    Missing modules:
    ? _md5 imported from hashlib
    ? _sha1 imported from hashlib
    ? _sha256 imported from hashlib
    ? _sha512 imported from hashlib
    ? readline imported from cmd
```

Then, after generation when i run the app i get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
        exec(code, m.__dict__)
      File "proactive-agent", line 5, in <module>
```

What did i miss ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem comes from the application itself and not from a bad generation of the standalone. My fault.

The app was referencing a file with a relative path, after generation the relative path was invalid since after generation the app itself was inside build/exe.macosx-10.5-i386-3.1/library.zip/myapp ...